# Is it possible to declare a variable of unknown type as a class member variable?

Tags: c++, templates, mersenne-twister

So I've been interested by the mersenne_twister engine and what it can do, so I decided to put the few lines of code required to initialize it inside my own class so that i simply have to create an instance of that class and can get any random numbers in any range i want without having to repeat those lines every time I need it.

I have suceeded so far but because I want my code to be as portble and efficient as possible I want to use the 64-bit engine depending on the architecture present.
I would like to avoid the way of using preprocessor macros defined by the compiler as that doesn't seem like the cleanest approach to me and would also require me to use the macros every time i mention the engine in my code.

My macro for the architecture l looks like this:

```
#define CPU_ARCH sizeof(nullptr)*8
```

And I declare the engine in the private space of the class so that i can init it in the constructor like this:

```
engine = mt19937(seed);
```

and use it in my random function like this:

```
double Random::giveRnd() {
    return distribution(engine);
}
```

This looks fine right now but I have yet to find a way to implement both architectures with the same name "engine" in a way that the engine to be used is chosen at startup.

I have attempted the following:

- Using a template to create a variable named engine that later gets
  assigned either mt19337 or mt19337_64 which results in the compiler
  complaining that

  error: data member 'engine' cannot be a member template

with the following implementation:

```
class Random {
      public:
      [...]

      private:
      template<typename T>
      T engine;

      [...]
};
```

- Using boost::variant which requires me to tell
  my giveRnd() function which type to use when I use the engine which
  is not possible since the type is not known at compile time
- Not declaring the engine in the header file at all although this
  results in the giveRnd() function not being able to use the engine
  because it is not in the same scope.
- Using preprocessor macros in the header file and then use typeid in
  the source code to find out which engine was used, which doesn't seem
  to be possible like this:

  if(CPU_ARCH==32) { engine = mt19337(seed) }

  because the compiler doesn't know that the engine will always be
  32-bit in this case and complains that I cannot use the '=' operator 
  on two different types.

Does anyone have an idea on how to make this possible in a atleast somewhat clean way? Or do I need to fall back on the preprocessor macros?

Comment: " would also require me to use the macros every time i mention the engine in my code."  Why?  You could have your code use those macros to define something else that you could reference consistently as needed.  Or just conditionally declare a using EngineType=<one> #else using EngineType=<other>, right?

Comment: Please ask a specific programming question (code, goal, and technical hurdle you want help with) and provide the code for what you have done so far [mcve].   Stack Overflow is not for code reviews or design suggestions.

Comment: @M.M could you give an example on how to implement that? I am not that familiar with templates in general and I can't figure out why making it static is necessary and how CPU_ARCH can be implemented in the template.

Comment: @xaxxon I don't like the predefined macros because they vary from comiler to compiler and I can't use CPU_ARCH in a #if statement because the preprocessor doent know what sizeof(nullptr) is before compiling the file.

Comment: @M.M I see, no I don't really need one, it would be cool if there could be just for the rare chance I ever need it but it is not necessary if it would complicate the code too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement behaviour that depends on `CPU_BITS` by making a class template that takes `CPU_BITS` as a template argument, and is specialized for expected values. For example:

```
#include <random>

template<size_t N> struct CpuOpts;
template<> struct CpuOpts<32> { using EngineType = std::mt19937; };
template<> struct CpuOpts<64> { using EngineType = std::mt19937_64; };

enum { CPU_BITS = sizeof(nullptr)*8 };
using CurrentCpuOpts = CpuOpts<CPU_BITS>;

struct Random
{
    CurrentCpuOpts::EngineType engine;
};

int main()
{
    Random r;
    r.engine.seed(123456);
}
```

Comment: After some googling to find out why this works :D I have successfully implemented this into my class with only one modifications, removing the `struct Random` around the `Engine<CPU_BITS>::type engine;` to simplify it just that little bit more or was there a specific reason you did that other than readability? Also is the `engine.seed` equivalent to `engine(seed)`? Other than that this is perfect for my purpose, thank you very much for saving me hours of my time :D

Comment: @TheSupremeGod You had the `Random` class in your original code.  Yes, calling the `seed` function is equivalent to seeding on creation.

Comment: Okay so before I blindly take your edit from `Engine` to `CpuOpts` into my code and go to bed trying to figure out what the _Opts_ means, could you tell me? Sorry for being the most nitpicky programmer in the world :D